# Responsive html app design to use default device font family and size?

Tags: android, html, ios, css, fonts

I did an extensive search for the best solution to be able to use default device font family and size in html applications but I just could not find any definitive solution. 
iOs 7 uses Helvetica font, Android 4.x uses Roboto font which supposedly can be got by:
font-family: sans-serif-light;
There is a ton of suggestions for using custom fonts but not much on using default fonts and sizes otherwise available in native apps.

This is the css compiled from various suggestions:

```
html {
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif-light;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: It depends. If you want absolute control over your fonts use @font-face and load web fonts. Otherwise define fonts from various systems - Windows, Mac, iOS and Android. I'd recommend using `font-weight: normal;`

Comment: I do not want to define my own fonts. What would be the css to get default font for iOS and Android?

Comment: Why specify font CSS at all?  It seems by "default" you mean not browser's default but OS UI default.  But is this really a problem—does browser default differ from system default?

Answer (score 0):

In your exaple font stack you should put `sans-serif-light` before `Helvetica` because when Android sees `helvetica` (not sure if case sensitive) it substitutes Roboto, as specified in
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/data/fonts/system_fonts.xml.

Also remember that [IE6 doesn't do per-character fallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family), so you may want to put Windows font(s) first (`Segoe UI, Tahoma, ...`).

But I'm not convinced listing what you believe are default  fonts is a win compared to not specifying anything (or just using a generic `sans-serif`).  Consider for example [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511282.aspx):

> Segoe UI is optimized for ClearType ... With ClearType enabled, Segoe UI is an elegant, readable font. Without ClearType enabled, Segoe UI is only marginally acceptable. This factor determines when you should use Segoe UI.

There is always the tradeoff when specifying any font(s) that the user/system default might be smarter / more usable.  This doesn't generally stop people but in your case the *desired font* is very close (or equal?) to the default anyway, so maybe letting the system decide is safer...

I found [this](http://examples.strictquirks.nl/test-font.html) and [this](http://help.dottoro.com/lclmgrtl.php) that list a bunch of internal font "names" browsers use for UI elements.   `-webkit-system-font` and `-moz-system-font` stand out as maybe what you want.  But I didn't find official documentation and these are certainly not standartized so I would be scared of these; naming specific fonts like Helvetica should give more predictable results.